# Changing Crystal Setting: "Overridden Qualified Table Name" in code

Tags: crystal-reports

I have no issues setting pretty much any connection value in a report except for this one. I am using XI R2 and I have tried CRAXDDRT as well as the .Net SDK.

Has anyone had luck doing this?

BTW, the reason I want to do this is because I want the report to target the database specified in the system DSN instead of the the 'catalog' value in the report. I can set this value manually but there are too many reports to do this by hand.

Thanks in advance

EDIT: Sorry I somehow cut off the part where I mention the name of the field giving me troubles :)

It is the field "Overridden Qualified Table Name"

Comment: Which setting are you trying to change? Am I missing something?

Comment: Do you want to tell us the connection value you are having trouble with?

Comment: Sorry about that. I added the field name to the question now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking back on the research a colleague and I did on this issue, we came to the conclusion that the rpt cannot be changed in code. I pondered using AutoIt but we decided to simply set the connection at runtime, which required building a crystal export tool.